# How to start background process and terminate in maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a background daemon `./debugger` that I need to start before all surefire tests and kill after all of them completed or failed. The daemon can save its pid to pidfile provided by command line argument, so I can start it with `./debugger --pid=debugger.pid` and stop with `kill -TERM $(cat debugger.pid)`.

Is it possible to configure maven in `pom.xml` to start this daemon before tests and stop after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tests need pre and post processing, it would be more suitable to run them in the integration test phase. You can use the failsafe plugin for that

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html